# How do you interpret impulse response function values?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, macroeconomics, impulse-response

I'm trying to figure out how to interpret the output values of an impulse response function.
Consider a VAR model with 3 variables and 8 lags. The variables are, in order, gdp-gap, inflation expectations and inflation. All 3 variables are in percent. The output from the irf-function looks like this:

```
Impulse response coefficients
$gdp_gap
        gdp_gap     inf_exp        inf
 [1,] 0.4608019 0.006631498 0.04119839
 [2,] 0.4187277 0.069217365 0.02516435
 [3,] 0.5107779 0.121386744 0.10315124
 [4,] 0.6597188 0.114528385 0.08245774
 [5,] 0.6955084 0.160748558 0.11726908
 [6,] 0.5324843 0.177680904 0.14030465
 [7,] 0.5682124 0.159188343 0.13292187
 [8,] 0.4424093 0.186714328 0.16163860
 [9,] 0.3008592 0.228591536 0.22543720
[10,] 0.2255207 0.205501820 0.21848705
[11,] 0.1909380 0.230703901 0.26689915
```

In case it is helpful, the code in R looks like this:

```
irf(VAR_1.5, impulse = "gdp_gap", ortho = x, boot = y, seed = 1234, n.ahead = 10))
```

Now when I look at the results, I notice a few things. 1. The chock to GDP seems to have an increasing impact on inflation expectations and inflation. 2. It seems to increase over time and 3. The chock to GDP seems quite big (even though I'm not sure in what units they are).

Ignoring confidence intervals, for now, is it correct to say that the first number represents 46%? 0.46%?

The plot looks like this:

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated!

EDIT, standard deviations:

gdp-gap
0.4608019

inf exp
0.3182719

inflation
0.3310615

**EDIT 2:**

```
# For data (downloading, manipulating and statistics)
library(dplyr)
library(pxweb)
library(TS)
library(lmtest)
library(vars)

# INFLATION

# PXWEB query
px1 <-
  list("ContentsCode"=c("PR0101F1"),
       "Tid"=c("*"))

# Download data
inf_px_data <-
  pxweb_get(url = "http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/en/ssd/PR/PR0101/PR0101G/KPIF",
            query = px1)

# Convert to data.frame
inf <- as.data.frame(inf_px_data, column.name.type = "text", variable.value.type = "text")


# INFLATION EXP
# PXWEB query
px2 <-
  list("Fråga"=c("Q061"),
       "Serie"=c("T"),
       "Grupp"=c("100"),
       "Period"=c("2002M01","2002M02","2002M03","2002M04","2002M05","2002M06","2002M07","2002M08","2002M09","2002M10","2002M11","2002M12","2003M01","2003M02","2003M03","2003M04","2003M05","2003M06","2003M07","2003M08","2003M09","2003M10","2003M11","2003M12","2004M01","2004M02","2004M03","2004M04","2004M05","2004M06","2004M07","2004M08","2004M09","2004M10","2004M11","2004M12","2005M01","2005M02","2005M03","2005M04","2005M05","2005M06","2005M07","2005M08","2005M09","2005M10","2005M11","2005M12","2006M01","2006M02","2006M03","2006M04","2006M05","2006M06","2006M07","2006M08","2006M09","2006M10","2006M11","2006M12","2007M01","2007M02","2007M03","2007M04","2007M05","2007M06","2007M07","2007M08","2007M09","2007M10","2007M11","2007M12","2008M01","2008M02","2008M03","2008M04","2008M05","2008M06","2008M07","2008M08","2008M09","2008M10","2008M11","2008M12","2009M01","2009M02","2009M03","2009M04","2009M05","2009M06","2009M07","2009M08","2009M09","2009M10","2009M11","2009M12","2010M01","2010M02","2010M03","2010M04","2010M05","2010M06","2010M07","2010M08","2010M09","2010M10","2010M11","2010M12","2011M01","2011M02","2011M03","2011M04","2011M05","2011M06","2011M07","2011M08","2011M09","2011M10","2011M11","2011M12","2012M01","2012M02","2012M03","2012M04","2012M05","2012M06","2012M07","2012M08","2012M09","2012M10","2012M11","2012M12","2013M01","2013M02","2013M03","2013M04","2013M05","2013M06","2013M07","2013M08","2013M09","2013M10","2013M11","2013M12","2014M01","2014M02","2014M03","2014M04","2014M05","2014M06","2014M07","2014M08","2014M09","2014M10","2014M11","2014M12","2015M01","2015M02","2015M03","2015M04","2015M05","2015M06","2015M07","2015M08","2015M09","2015M10","2015M11","2015M12","2016M01","2016M02","2016M03","2016M04","2016M05","2016M06","2016M07","2016M08","2016M09","2016M10","2016M11","2016M12","2017M01","2017M02","2017M03","2017M04","2017M05","2017M06","2017M07","2017M08","2017M09","2017M10","2017M11","2017M12","2018M01","2018M02","2018M03","2018M04","2018M05","2018M06","2018M07","2018M08","2018M09","2018M10","2018M11","2018M12","2019M01","2019M02","2019M03","2019M04","2019M05","2019M06","2019M07","2019M08","2019M09","2019M10","2019M11","2019M12","2020M01","2020M02","2020M03","2020M04","2020M05","2020M06","2020M07","2020M08","2020M09","2020M10","2020M11","2020M12","2021M01","2021M02","2021M03","2021M04","2021M05","2021M06","2021M07","2021M08","2021M09","2021M10","2021M11","2021M12","2022M01","2022M02"))


# Download data
inf_exp_temp <-
  pxweb_get(url = "http://statistik.konj.se/PXWeb/api/v1/en/KonjBar/hushall/HushallInfRant.px",
            query = px2)
# Convert to data.frame
inf_exp <- as.data.frame(inf_exp_temp, column.name.type = "text", variable.value.type = "text")


# GDP_GAP

# PXWEB query
px5 <-
  list("variabel"=c("F2404Gapp"),
       "enhet"=c("N"),
       "period"=c("88","89","90","91","92","93","94","95","96","97","98","99","100","101","102","103","104","105","106","107","108","109","110","111","112","113","114","115","116","117","118","119","120","121","122","123","124","125","126","127","128","129","130","131","132","133","134","135","136","137","138","139","140","141","142","143","144","145","146","147","148","149","150","151","152","153","154","155","156","157","158","159"))

# Download data
gdp_gap_data <-
  pxweb_get(url = "http://prognos.konj.se/PXWeb/api/v1/sv/TidigarePrognoser/Konjunkturlaget/20191009/f24_resursutnyttjande/F2404.px",
            query = px5)

# Convert to data.frame
gdp_gap <- as.data.frame(gdp_gap_data, column.name.type = "text", variable.value.type = "text")


# drop uneccessary columns

inf_exp <- inf_exp[ -c(1:3) ]
gdp_gap <- gdp_gap[ -c(1:2) ]


# rename variables
colnames(inf) <- c("month", "cpif")
colnames(inf_exp) <- c("month", "inf_exp")
colnames(gdp_gap) <- c("quarter", "gdp_gap")



##------------------------------------------------------
## Convert to ts()
##------------------------------------------------------


#
inf <- ts(inf[,2], start = c(1987, 1), frequency = 12)
inf_exp <- ts(inf_exp[,2], start = c(2002, 1), frequency = 12)
gdp_gap <- ts(gdp_gap[,2], start = c(2002, 1), frequency = 4)

# aggregate inf and inf_exp to quarterly data
inf <- aggregate(inf, FUN = mean, nfrequency = 4)
inf_exp <- aggregate(inf_exp, FUN = mean, nfrequency = 4)

# Syncronize periods
inf <- window(inf, start = c(2002, 1), end = c(2019, 4))
inf_exp <- window(inf_exp, start = c(2002, 1), end = c(2019, 4))
gdp_gap <- window(gdp_gap, start = c(2002, 1), end = c(2019, 4))

##-------------- Combine ts objects

all_vars <- ts.intersect(gdp_gap, inf_exp, inf)



##------------------------------------------------------
## Build model w. dummies
##------------------------------------------------------

VAR_1 <- VAR(all_vars, p = 6, type = "none")
VAR_resid <- residuals(VAR_1)


inf_max <- VAR_resid[,1] == max(VAR_resid[,1])
inf_min <- VAR_resid[,1] == min(VAR_resid[,1])
infexp_max <- VAR_resid[,2] == max(VAR_resid[,2])
infexp_min <- VAR_resid[,2] == min(VAR_resid[,2])
gdp_gap_max <- VAR_resid[,3] == max(VAR_resid[,3])
gdp_gap_min <- VAR_resid[,3] == min(VAR_resid[,3])


max_min <- ts(cbind(inf_min, infexp_max, infexp_min, gdp_gap_max), start = c(2003, 3), frequency = 4)

# Since we use 6 lags, we remove 6 quarters from the data

all_vars1.5 <- window(all_vars, start = c(2003, 3), frequency = 4)

VAR_1.5 <- VAR(all_vars1.5, p = 8, type = "none", exogen = max_min)

(g_gap1 <- irf(VAR_1.5, impulse = "gdp_gap", ortho = T, boot = T, seed = 1234, n.ahead = 10));plot(g_gap1)
```

Comment: With IRF's, it is the ambition to show how a one standard deviation shock in one variable transmits through to another variable. For example, how a one standard deviation inflation shock affects inflation expectations. This is a more interesting specification than the one you have above.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate? Do you mean to say that the numbers are not in standard deviations? Can you explain why that would be more interesting?

Comment: Hi @Tomas. In terms of content, the economic perspective I proposed above is self-evidently more interesting in terms of understanding economic relationships through time and the implications for policy. I am an economist, but this is not the right site for that kinda chat. In terms of your IRFs, to understand the units on the vertical axis, and thus the amount by which a shock transmits (holding all else equal), you have to know the the size of your standard deviations. This is necessary prior to understanding your graphs correctly.

Comment: @EBB3112 Added std.dev. to the question. I can see that the initial chock is 1 standard deviation. How can I interpret the response?

Comment: Hi @Tomas. On the vertical axis of the first panel, this does not mean that the shock is equal to one standard deviation in the first period (this is the point I made above). Instead, you first have to derive your standard deviations, and thus get the magnitude of standard deviations, prior to interpreting the IRFs. (i.e. you have to first obtain some descriptive statistics prior to running your analysis).

Comment: I would encourage you to generate some graphs where a shock to one variable is expressed in terms of another variable. If you upload these, alongside your standard deviations, people can start to provide not only some interpretation of the IRF, but also some economic content.

Comment: Now I'm a bit confused. Maybe I wasn't clear about this. The 3 plots show the reaction to a shock in the GDP-gap variable. As I said, I added the standard deviations to the question.

Comment: Please stop posting screenshots of code. Instead, please post the code as text and format it appropriately.

Comment: @RichardHardy I've added a small reprex without the preceding statistical test. Also, the plots are created w plot() instead of ggplot to save space. Is this enough code? Just to be clear, I'm mostly interested in the statistical interpretation - as in which units are the irf output in..

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong to call it code. What I meant is the output, i.e the picture following the text *The output from the irf-function looks like this*. That should be changed from a screenshot to text formatted as code. The same holds for your other posts.

Comment: Of course, that makes more sense.  I've done that now and will fix the other posts in a moment. I guess I'll leave the reprex  in? Some people ask for this.